# How can I send data from kafka to hive

Tags: hive, apache-kafka

I want to send data from Kafka (doing some MapReduce job) to hive.
Is this suitable to use spark streaming?
OR some better ways?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Kafka Connect](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/index.html) and the HDFS connector to do this. This streams data from Kafka to HDFS, and defines the Hive table on top automatically. It's available [standalone](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs) or as part of [Confluent Platform](https://www.confluent.io/download/).

*Disclaimer: I work for Confluent.*

Comment: Hi Robin, I'm using the Kafka HDFS Connector to stream a Kafka topic to Hive. But it seems that I can only query the data after the stream completed? But in my use case, the stream is not going to stop.

Comment: "it seems that I can only query the data after the stream completed" -> no, that's not the case. As you say, streams are unbounded.

Comment: You're better off starting a new question with the specific issue you're encountering, than adding comments to an existing one.

Comment: Robin, do you know if there is a portal for users who can get quick response when they get problems? Since, i think the using of confluent is not always programming related, so post questions on SO won't be a good choice then.

Answer (score 1):

From a streaming perspective, Hive tables built ahead of time, dumped into using Spark Streaming or Flink will work fine, for the most part, but what if the schema of the Hive output in the Spark job changes? That's where you might want something like [Streamsets](https://streamsets.com/blog/ingesting-drifting-data-hive-impala/), Kafka Connect HDFS Connector, or Apache Gobblin

Also, keep in mind, HDFS doesn't like dealing with tiny files, so setting up a large batch size ahead of HDFS would be beneficial for later Hive consumption

Comment: is writing a consumer app that dumping data into a CSV file, then load to a specific Hive table a good way to achieve this?

Comment: @Den I would avoid that as the consumer should be stateless and able to rebalance or at the very least, have fault tolerance built in . What's wrong with the listed options?

Comment: thanks for your reply. I think using Spark streaming is a good option to take a try, but just feel a little bit heavy. anyway, I should have a try.

Answer (score 1):

There's already one Hive-Kafka ETL practice in Hive document.

The users are able to create an external table that is a view over one Kafka topic

For more info:
https://github.com/apache/hive/tree/master/kafka-handler

Comment: This queries kafka directly. There's no L here and there's no historical access which is common for Hive.

Comment: no, there is a ETL practice, you can check the chapter titled 'Kafka to Hive ETL Pipeline Example' inside the document.